# awk how to print the rest

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

my file contains lines like this

```
any1 aaa bbb ccc
```

The delimiter is space. the number of words in the line is unknown

I want to put the first word into a `var1`. It's simple with

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

Now I want to put the rest of the line into a `var2` with awk.

How I can print the rest of the line with `awk` ?

Answer (score 3):

Better to use `read` here:

```
s="any1 aaa bbb ccc"
read var1 var2 <<< "$s"
echo "$var1"
any1
echo "$var2"
aaa bbb ccc
```

For `awk` only solution use:

```
echo "$s" | awk '{print $1; print substr($0, index($0, " ")+1)}'
any1
aaa bbb ccc
```

Comment: what about awk '{$1 = ""; print $0;}'`

Comment: @EdMorton would have excruciated me if I had given that hack in my answer :) so no that's not the right way because it leaves delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

awk solution:

```
awk '{$1 = ""; print $0;}'`
```

Comment: No that's not right because it will print 1 or more spaces after `$1`

Comment: It will print exactly 1 space before the new first field (which was the original 2nd field) and it will also compress all other contiguous white spaces to single blank chars. It also has unnecessary trailing semi-colon and `$0` and even the `; print $0;}` could idiomatically just be `}1` (but it'd still have the problems with spaces).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ var=$(awk '{sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")}1' file)
$ echo "$var"
aaa bbb ccc
```

or in general to skip some number of fields use a RE interval:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){1}/,"")}1' file
aaa bbb ccc
$ awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/,"")}1' file
bbb ccc
$ awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}/,"")}1' file
ccc
```

Note that doing this gets much more complicated if you have a FS that's more than a single char, and the above is just for the default FS since it additionally skips any leading blanks if present (remove the first `[[:space:]]*` if you have a non-default but still single-char FS).